# YourCompleteMe vim enables function error?

Tags: vim

Boa noite, é o seguinte, eu instalei o famoso yourcompleteme do vim para me auxilar em alguns snippets que configurei no editor e outros de terceiros, quando eu inicio o editor ele me retorna esse warning da tela com a seguinte mensagem
Erro detectado ao processar function youcompleteme#Enable..122_SetUpSettings
como eu não tenho tanta experiência com o plugin, eu fiquei curioso em tentar resolver este problema.

Comment: Confesso que não sei a resposta para seu problema. Uma coisa que você pode tentar é temporariamente desativar outros plugins sem ser o youcompleteme (pra ver se tem alguma incompatibilidade) ou tentar reinstalar o youcompleteme (eu me lembro das instruções serembem complicadas... quem sabe você não pulou um passo...)

Comment: Como você instalou? Recomendo usar o [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) para isso.

Comment: eu usei o neobundle e compilei ele, acabei que abandonando o yourcomepleteme e usando o neocomplete...obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 0):

Após a instalação o **YCM** deverá ser compilado gerando o suporte semântico.
Ao instalar o **Youcompleteme** o **./install.py** deverá ser executado

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.py --clang-completer
```

Fonte: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#installation